# TFS wont send out alert mails anymore?

Tags: tfs

We have been using TFS with Visual Studio 2010 for quite sometime and untill yesterday the mail notifications(alerts) were being sent out properly .

Since today morning however it has stopped working and i am not able to figure out why ?

Any suggestions as to what could be wrong  ?

Comment: When we had a similar situation, it proved to be an Exchange issue

Answer (score 0):

You can get some good error information by setting the [NotificationJobLogLevel to 2](http://healmyscm.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/how-to-set-tfss-notification-job-log-level/) and then querying the [JobHistory](http://healmyscm.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/how-to-check-tfs-event-delivery-status-for-the-web-service/) table in the database. This *should* show you any errors that are occurring.