# TFS 2012 Event Notification

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I want to handle an event of TFS, such as WorkItemChangeEvent.

I wrote a Class Library that writes a description to eventlog. Then I add it under Plugins folder of TFS. When the event occures, there is no description about it on eventlog.

Here is the code:
http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/10/27/devleoping-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010.aspx

I'm using TFS 2012 nad Visual Studio 2011 Beta

Answer (score 0):

You can search event notifications in table `tbl_eventSubscription` in the  `tfs_ProjectCollectionName` database.

In order to check if data is saved in the database or not you can also check `Server Manager\Diagnostics\Event Viewer\Custom Views\Server Roles\Administrative Events`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338230/tfs-wont-send-out-alert-mails-anymore) I posted here for help debugging TFS Events.

---

I copied the details here:

> You can get some good error information by setting the [NotificationJobLogLevel to 2](http://healmyscm.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/how-to-set-tfss-notification-job-log-level/) and then 
>   querying the [JobHistory](http://healmyscm.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/how-to-check-tfs-event-delivery-status-for-the-web-service/) table in the database. This *should* show you any errors that are 
>   occurring.